# How to handle the multiple rows are INSERT or UPDATE in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, insert-update

My trigger can handle one record is INSERT/UPDATE.Now I need to handle the multiple rows are insert/update.

Some one can please help me. How to fix the issue.

**Code:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER Notifications ON CUSTOMER
FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @oldname varchar(20)
    DECLARE @newname varchar(20)
    DECLARE @recordId INT
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
        Select @oldname = customerName.o,@newname = customerName.o FROM inserted n,deleted o
        PRINT @newname
        PRINT @oldname
        IF @newname != @oldname
        BEGIN
            EXEC StoredProcedure1 @recordId
        END
        --Here I can implemnent my own logic
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        Select @newname = customerName.o FROM inserted
        PRINT @newname
            EXEC StoredProcedure1 @recordId
        -- Here I can implemnent my own logic
    END
END
```

Comment: If you have to execute a proc from your trigger, you will need to do a CURSOR.   It would be more performant if you could incorporate your proc logic into your trigger.

Comment: Be aware that since your FROM clause in your first SELECT doesn't specify a join condition, you'll get a cross join between `inserted` and `deleted`.  If you have multiple records in either table, you'll get some odd-looking, incorrect results.

Comment: What does `StoredProcedure1` do?  Is it something that you could either incorporate into your trigger or cause to work on multiple `@recordID` values?  (Where does `@recordID` get its value from, anyway?)

Comment: @Ann L. ,The StoredProcedure1 send an email to customers